# Как в бранче отменить мерж?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

В рабочем бранче сделал мерж с другой веткой. Были конфликты которые я нормально не смог пофиксить и на скорую руку сделал `git reset HEAD~`
Вопрос, что я сделал и как вернуть состояние до мержа?

Comment: Сделайте `git checkout хеш коммита до мержа`. Все, теперь HEAD (это указатель) там где вам нужно. Поймите, что ветки, коммиты - все это граф. Вы можете переключиться на любой узел. Тот "неудачный" мерж останется как "тупиковая ветвь".

Comment: `git reset <hash>` делает сброс индекса до состояния `<hash>`, дальше два варианта, либо куда-то сложить эти изменения, либо таки выбросить.

Comment: @TotalPusher, не совсем чётко, `<merge_hash>^1`, где `<merge_hash>` -- как раз указатель на на слияние.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset HEAD~` удаляет все что не было закомичено и возвращает `HEAD` к предыдущему комиту, т.е. удаляет все текущие изменения и последний комит. Поэтому, чтобы вернуть назад последний комит надо сделать еще раз  `git reset --hard <комит>`.

Comment: Ну а сам merge как бы и есть коммит? Т.е. когда я сделал `git merge another_yet_branch` а потом `git reset HEAD~` то у меня стало все как до мержа?

Comment: да, так и стало